# Are invariant sets preserved under topological equivalence?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Let $F_1,F_2 \in \mathcal{C}^1(U)$ with flow maps $\phi_t^{F_1}, \phi^{F_2}_t$. The two vector fields are topologically equivalent , denoted by $F_1 \simeq F_2 \, $ if there exists a homeomorphism $h: U \rightarrow U$, mapping orbits of the first system onto
orbits of the second system, i.e.
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \ \forall x \in U: \quad \phi^{F_1}_t(x)=h^{-1} \circ \phi^{F_2}_{\tau} \circ h(x),$$
with $ \tau: U \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \frac{\partial \tau(x,t)}{\partial t} >0 \quad \forall x \in U $. This means the time direction of the orbits is preserved.

We call a set $S \subset U$ invariant if

$$\forall x \in S: \quad \phi_t(x) \in S \quad \forall t$$

---

**My question is the following:** Are invariant sets, invariant under topological equivalence? I.e. let $S$ be an invariant set of $F_1$, is $S$ then also an invariant set of $F_2$?

---

I know this holds for FPs and limit cycles. But is it generally true for invariant sets?

Comment: Not in general. If $S$ is invariant under $F_1$, then $h(S)$ is invariant under $F_2$, and there is no reason for $h(S) = S$ to be true.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for the comment. But this means that the number of e.g. FPs need to be the same for $F_1,F_2$. But their positions does not in general need to match? So if $F_1$ has a FP at $x_1$, $F_2$ has it at $h(x_1)=F(x_2)\neq x_1$

Comment: Yes the number of fixed points is preserved, but not their location. The number of invariant sets is also preserved, as are many of the properties of those invariant sets. But location is not preserved. $h$ can move it around pretty freely. Indeed, everything in these definitions still works if you have $F_1$ defined on $U_1$ and $F_2$ defined on $U_2$ with $U_1$ being homeomorphic to $U_2$, but not necessary the same set, or even overlapping sets. In the later case, $S$ being invariant under both is non-sensical, as it is only in the domain of one of them.